# Remove Decimals from Array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays containing zeros & ones. I want to perform hstack() on them but not getting the desired output.

Python Code..

```
 import numpy as np
 zeros = np.zeros(8)
 ones = np.ones(8)
 zerosThenOnes = np.hstack((zeros, ones))   # A 1 by 16 array
```

Current Output..

```
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

Expected Output..

```
 [ 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 ]
```

I can't understand what silly mistake I'm doing.

Comment: Try using np.zeros((8,), dtype=numpy.int), and np.ones((8,), dtype=numpy.int).

Answer (score 1):

You must tell numpy to return the values as integers

```
import numpy as np

zeros = np.zeros((8,), dtype=np.int)
ones = np.ones((8,), dtype=np.int)
zerosThenOnes = np.hstack((zeros, ones))
```

To print out `zerosThenOnes` like this `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

Use:

```
print([x for x in zerosThenOnes])
```

[Numpy Zeros](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

Comment: I have a question, is [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] == [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] ??? If not then how to modify your code to get the LHS result with commas?

Comment: Wrong, np.zeros(8, dtype=np.int) won't work. Neither np.ones(8, dtype=np.int). Right: np.zeros((8,), dtype=numpy.int), and np.ones((8,), dtype=numpy.int), as commented above.

Comment: @Lucy, you can always run print [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] == [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] and find out!

Comment: printing LHS will introduce commas..but how do i get the same output using hstack in the solution above?

Comment: @user60312321: What's wrong with `np.zeros(8, dtype=np.int)`?

Comment: Seems like it works fine (can't test, but searching). I usually follow the docs. Anyways I should have tested before. Sorry @Russel and thanks @Warren!

Answer (score 0):

`np.hstack((np.zeros(8), np.ones(8))).astype(int)`

for `np.array` output, or

`map( int, np.hstack((np.zeros(8), np.ones(8))) )`

for `list` output